# Opening file Dialog with context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am working to create a Web Extension for both google chrome and Firefox.
Ultimately my goal is to **open a file dialogue when I click on the context menu item added by my extension**.  However, there are two major problems when trying to do this.

1. The file dialogue must be opened by user action that activates an input element with type=file.
2. Context menu events are added and called from the background script of the extension.

Is there a silver bullet solution I am missing?

**Failed Solutions**

1. Background input element:  Input elements will not function when used in the background script.
2. Message Passing (works on Chrome but not Firefox): Sending a message from the background to the content script keeps its user triggered status on chrome, but loses it in Firefox.

*For those interested: this is the code that works in Chrome but not Firefox.*

Background.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
 title: "Clickme",
 contexts:["image"],  // ContextType
 onclick: function(){sendMsg("openDialog")} // Called when clicked in menu
});
```

Content.js:

```
var fInput= document.createElement("input"); //hidden input to open filedialog
fInput.setAttribute("type", "file"); //opens files
fInput.setAttribute("id", "fileopeninput"); ////only useful for inspector debugging

///TAKE MESSAGE FROM Background
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.msg === "openDialog"){
        fInput.click(); //triggers open file dialogue
    }
});
```

Comment: Firefox does not allow to open file dialog without a user gesture until user grant permission to open the dialog.

Comment: It's definitely a bug in Firefox - right-click doesn't grant the permission and the dialog is blocked (if FF is configured to block popup windows in its settings) even if I do it in the content script using `mouseup` event listener without any background page, whereas left-click shows the file dialog successfully without being blocked.

Comment: It's been 5 years, has this been updated?